# PHP - Will fwrite() save the file immediately?

Tags: php, file-io

This is my code:

```
$zplHandle = fopen($target_file,'w');
fwrite($zplHandle, $zplBlock01);
fwrite($zplHandle, $zplBlock02);
fwrite($zplHandle, $zplBlock03);
fclose($zplHandle);
```

When will the file be saved? Is it immediately after writing to it or after closing it?

I am asking this because I have [Printfil](http://www.printfil.com/) listening to files in a folder and prints any file that is newly created. If PHP commits a save immediately after `fwrite`, I may run into issues of Printfil not capturing the subsequent writes.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a tiny piece of code to test it and it seems that after `fwrite` the new content will be detected immediately,not after `fclose`.

Here's my test on Linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$f = fopen("file.txt","a+");
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    sleep(1);
    fwrite($f,"something\n");
    echo $i," write ...\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "stop write";
?>
```

After running the PHP script ,I use `tail -f file.txt` to detect the new content.And It shows new contents the same time as php's output tag.

Comment: OK. At least that gives some idea on the possibility of a flush before the intended time. I shall work on things based on your test results. Thanks Spawn!

Comment: I feel like this answer is a bit misleading... as on busy systems or if other factors are in play the write time will vary. But using @Sjoerd answer, you can guarantee the write time using `fflush()`.

Answer (score 12):

PHP may or may not write the content immediately. There is a caching layer in between. You can force it to write using [fflush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php), but you can't force it to wait unless you use only one fwrite().

Comment: True; OTOH, it will definitely write the content (and release file locks) when you call fclose().

Comment: @Piskvor: When will the folder monitoring software recognise the newly created file? Will it be after a save or after the lock release? This is crucial because there are some 8000 blocks of text content to be written to the file and the monitoring program should not be triggered anywhere in between. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I don't know, ask the people of PrintFil.

Comment: @Sjoerd Is there a way to switch that chaching on or off? If so, how?

Comment: @Julian, no, not with `fwrite`. You can use the [direct I/O](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php) module if you want more control over your writes.

Comment: @Sjoerd, Does fclose imply fflush?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, the file is flushed when it's closed.

Answer (score 4):

the file will be saved on fclose. if you want to put the content to the file before, use [fflush()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your working in PHP 5.x, try file_put_contents() instead, as it wraps the open/write/close into one call.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php